Proving an exponential sum inequality for symmetric Hamming distance sequences in binary vectors
Background: Let $X = \{0,1\}^k$ represent the set of all binary vectors of length $k$. For two binary vectors $x, y \in X$, the Hamming distance $d_H(x, y)$ is defined as the number of positions where $x$ and $y$ differ, serving as a measure of similarity between these vectors.
Problem Setup: Let $k_0$ and $k'$ be integers with $k_0, k' \geq \frac{k}{2}$(we may let $k_0\leq k'$). Define $x_0 \in X$ as a vector in which the first $k_0$ entries are $0$, and the remaining entries are $1$. Let $A = \{ x_i \in X \mid \text{the number of zeros in } x_i \text{ is exactly } k' \}$. For each $x_i \in A$, let $a_i = d_H(x_0, x_i)$, the Hamming distance between $x_0$ and $x_i$. Denote the sequence of Hamming distances as $\{ a_i \}$, and let $a = \frac{1}{|A|} \sum a_i$ represent the mean of this sequence. Define a new sequence $\{ a'_i \}$ such that for each $i$, $2a = a_i + a'_i$. This construction makes $\{ a_i \}$ and $\{ a'_i \}$ symmetric around the mean $a$.

(As noted by Fedor Petrov)Note that $a=k_0+k'-2(k_0\cdot k')/k$ using the linearity of expectation, and the number of $a_i$ which equal to $u$ is $\binom{k_0}{u_1} \binom{k - k_0}{u_2}$ (where $u_1 = \frac{u - k' + k_0}{2}, u_2 = \frac{u + k' - k_0}{2}$).

Question: I am seeking to prove the inequality
$$\sum \exp(a_i) \leq \sum \exp(a'_i).$$

Or, could we perhaps prove a weaker version? There exist a constant $c$ independent with $k_0,k',k$ such that:
$$\sum \exp(a_i) \leq c\sum \exp(a'_i).$$


Can Karamata's inequality be applied here? Or are there other methods we could consider for this type of problem?

Why do you think this inequality is true?

well, because I guess the distribution function(f(x):=the number of a_i which equals x) of ${a_i}$ is symmetric(or have some "symmetric" property) but I'm not sure. If symmetric then its equal. @IosifPinelis

When $k' = k_0$, the distribution is symmetric, and the inequality holds with equality. Additionally, I feel that as $k'$ increases, the difference between the right side and the left side of the inequality grows, but I am unsure how to prove this. @IosifPinelis

This is just what can be initial steps in a complete answer to this interesting question.
Let $s:=k_0$ and $t:=k'$. Then $|A|=\binom{k}{t}$. Denoting by $u$ the number of zero entries in $x\in A$ among the first $s$ entries of $x$, we see that $d_H(x,x_0)=s+t-2u$. So, the mean of $d_H(x,x_0)$ over $x\in A$ is
$$a=a(k,s,t):=\frac{1}{\binom{k}{t}}\,\sum _{u=0}^s (s+t-u)\binom{s}{u}  \binom{k-s}{t-u}.$$
(As noted by Fedor Petrov, $a=s+t-2st/k$.)
The left- and right-hand sides of the inequality in question are, respectively,
$$L(k,s,t):=\sum _{u=0}^s e^{s+t-2u}\binom{s}{u}  \binom{k-s}{t-u}$$
and
$$R(k,s,t):=e^{2 a(k,s,t)}\sum _{u=0}^s e^{-(s+t-2u)} 
\binom{s}{u} \binom{k-s}{t-u}.$$
Below is the table of values of the ratio $\dfrac{L(k,s,t)}{R(k,s,t)}$, rounded to three significant digits, for $k=2,\dots,10$, $s\in\{\lceil k/2\rceil,\dots,k\}$, and $t\in\{\lceil k/2\rceil,\dots,k\}$, with $s$ and $t$ being the row and column indices of the matrix of values of the ratio corresponding to one of the values of $k$. This table  suggests that the conjectured inequality is true (even though the supposed monotonicity in $t$ does not hold, of course).


By writing the random Hamming distance as the sum of $k$ 0/1 random variables corresponding to the coordinates, we get $a=s(1-t/k)+(k-s)t/k=s+t-2st/k$

For what it worth: $L(k, s, t) =e^{s+t}x^t^s(1+x)^{k-s}$,$R(k, s, t) =e^{s+t-4st/k}x^t^{s}(1+x)^{k-s}$

Thanks very much! By the way, do you think this question can be finally proved (or its weak version, allow a contact times it)? Could convex property (something like Karamata's inequality) be applied here for its prove? thank you!

@tomjerry : I will have this in mind.

Thanks! Now,I have an idea but not sure whether it's correct...for the weak version with $0.5k\leq k_0\leq k'\leq 0.5+o(1)k$ and $k$ very large(why consider this because when k large, #0-1 vector with (#0s>0.5+o(1)k)/(2^k) tend 0). By considering $f(u) = \binom{k_0}{\frac{u - k' + k_0}{2}} \binom{k - k_0}{\frac{u + k' - k_0}{2}}$ satisfies $\sum_{u\in a\pm d}f(u)/(\sum_{u\in a\pm d}1)\leq a$, thus for any $t\in\mathbb{R}^1$, $\sum_{a'_i \geq t} a'i \geq \sum{a_i \geq t} a_i.$ So we only need to solve this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4993913/question-on-exp-inequality

@tomjerry : That question is actually trivial.

Thanks very much! I'm reading your answer.

@FedorPetrov May I ask does these $k$ 0/1 random variable i.i.d.? And if $k$ is very very large, could we consider the distribution of $u$(the number of $a_i$ that equal to $u$) as two product of Gaussian(use Gaussian is easier to calculate than use Binomal)?

These variables are dependent, but identically distributed, and we still can find the expectation of each of them

@FedorPetrov Thanks! By the way, may I ask that I want to prove when $k$ is very large, for any $d>0$ the number of $a_i$ having Hamming  distance with $x_0$ leq $a-d$ is no less than the number of $a_i$ having Hamming  distance with $x_0$ geq $a-d$, could I consider the distribution of $u$ as two Gaussian function's product? i.e., repersent $f(u)=\binom{k_0}{\frac{u - k' + k_0}{2}} \binom{k - k_0}{ \frac{u + k' - k_0}{2}}$ as $g(u)=c_1\exp{c_2(u/2-k_0/2)^2+c_3(u/2-k/2+k_0/2)^2}$, and by compare the inetger of $g$ in two intervals to compare the sum of $f$ in two intervals?
